# Oracle - SELECT Statement to concat the same field in a record

Tags: sql, concatenation

I have a table TB_FT with two columns ID_FT NUMBER(PK) and NM_FT VARCHAR.

```
 Like:   ID_FT  NM_FT
           1    MYFT1
           2    MYFT2

 I have another table TB_CEL_FT with 2 columns ID_FT NUMBER(FK) and ID_CEL NUMBER
 Like:   ID_FT    ID_CEL
           1        10
           1        11
           2        30
           2        31
           2        32
```

I need to create an stored procedure that returns a sys_refcursor like that:

```
      ID_FT    CELS
        1      10,11
        2      30,21,32
```

I managed to work with the queries and store the result in a TYPE, but I need to find out how to return the result as a SYS_REFCURSOR.

Could you guys help me?
TIA
Luis

Answer (score 1):

Newer oracle's support listagg. You can use it like this:

```
select
  id_ft,
  listagg(id_cel, ',') within group (order by id_cel) cels,
from
  table
group by
  id_ft
```